# Выборка из базы исключая несколько записей

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite

Есть таблица с книгами и ссылками на них, а также таблица с загружаемыми/загруженными книгами. Как при выводе списка доступных книг убрать те, которые подлежат загрузке/загружены?

Попробовал накидать самый простой вариант в этой ситуации

```
String where = DBHelper.F_SUBJECT + " = " + subjectID + " AND " + DBHelper.P_ID + " NOT IN ('4,5,6,7,18,19,20')";
Cursor cursor = sdb.query(DBHelper.DT_MATERIALS, null, where, null, null, null, null);
```

Но почему-то не исключает записи с номерами 4,5,6,7,18,19,20. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: `('4,5,6,7,18,19,20')` поменяйте на `(4,5,6,7,18,19,20)`. Кавычки лишние у вас.

Answer (score 0):

Для более-менее конкретного ответа нужно бы подробнее схему базы данных знать, конечно.
Могу предложить использовать что-то вроде `LEFT OUTER JOIN` в запросе с проверкой на NULL.

```
SELECT 
  linkBook_table.book 
FROM 
  linkBook_table 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  loadBook_table 
ON 
  linkBook_table.book = loadBook_table.book
WHERE 
  loadBook_table.book IS NULL;
```

Должно работать.